# Read only 2 columns from a '~' delimited text file into dataframe and store second column as string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a very large text file (3.33 GB) which has 47 columns separated by delimiter `~`. I just need the first and the last column to work with. The last column is a 17 digit number which may contain leading zeros. I have to store this column as a string (so as to not remove the leading zeros). An example of the first and last column is shown below:

```py
   id   Number
0   0   10030040125198660
1 12345 60034046122158670
```

My question is whether it's possible to read just these two columns alone, and store the second column as string ? The reason I ask is because loading 3.3GB file as a dataframe takes a lot of time, converting it into string takes an even longer amount. I want to know if I can save time by choosing only the columns I need.

My code as of now (shown the column names as numbers for easy understanding):

```py
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',low_memory=False,sep='~',header=None)
df.drop(columns=[2,3,4...,46],inplace=True)                       #Keeping only column 1 and 47
df['47']=df['47'].astype(str)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: you can try passing `usecols=[0,46]` to `read_csv`.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang ! Can I convert a column to string while reading it in ?

Comment: Probably with `dtype={46:str}` option in `read_csv`

Comment: Thank You! I shall try this and let you know if there is any improvement in terms of time!

Answer (score 0):

You should use "usecols" parameter. Check out the read_csv official documentation. Infact that is the first thing you should check